# Numpy is installed but still getting some errors

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to run jupyter notebook and getting following error. I am using Win 7 with anaconda python 3.7.

> ImportError: Something is wrong with the numpy installation. While
>   importing we detected an older version of numpy in
>   ['C:\Users\shaher11\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy']. One
>   method of fixing this is to repeatedly uninstall numpy until none is
>   found, then reinstall this version.

i think it is the same problem that mentioned [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12976)

Comment: try the solution they're suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on python 3.6 (which I have to use for Keras) and  reinstalling using "conda remove numpy" and "conda install numpy" didn't do the trick.

What worked was using pip3 instead. i.e. "pip 3 install numpy"

I think conda was trying to install the wrong version of numpy for the python version.  Might be worth a try for your python 3.7 issue.

Answer (score 0):

"conda update --all" worked for me.

Also, for anyone trying this on Jupyter using GCP, open a terminal in Jupyter itself and run that command to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

This works in Python 3.6:
`conda install -c conda-forge numpy==1.19.5`. Neither `pip install` or `pip3 install` was able to resolve the `ImportError` in my case.